# Curl problems with headers

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, libcurl

I'm having a problem with the headers on CURL, my script have two parts, first the autentication and second the request, the first parte is working good, i'm getting the result code and an id, in the second part I set up the headers with that id and send it on the header, but i'm getting this error (< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized), but, i tryed now using an addon for firefox (ModifyHeaders) and I get now the response (I setted up the id on this software and accessing to the WS by URL), i don't know what is happening or how can i fix it,
here is the code:

```
$postargs = array('username' => 'user', 'password' => 'pass', 'key' => '1234567890');
$postargs = json_encode($postargs);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8","Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postargs);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ws.com/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
$fh = fopen('curl_debug.txt', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fh);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);            
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$a = json_decode($response);
echo $a->result;
curl_close($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ws.com/data");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("id : $a->result","dataRequest : name","Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8","Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
$fh2 = fopen('curl_debug2.txt', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fh2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$response2 = curl_exec($ch);
```

What is wrong in the script? why the headers (In this case the id) aren't going by script but yes by ModifyHeaders?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and point it to a writable (by the script) file. This will allow curl to save your session cookie in there.

Comment: Also a good idea to use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION in case the page redirects you to another page. (and ditch the curl_close like Ray says)

Answer (score 1):

The second request is a GET request after you just closed the authenticated curl connection and initialized a new one.  This is a completely  ew and unauthenticated request.  Your not passing the authentication array as you do in the POST.

Take a look at this: [Can I make more then one request on a curl connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479490/can-i-make-more-then-one-request-on-a-curl-connection)

Comment: Nice, let me check and thanks for the answer! i'll let you know guys if it works!

Comment: I edited the script, i taked off the first curl_close() and the second curl_ini(), but i'm facing the same problem, i'm looking the curl_multi now.